Positional Invariance missing after max pooling operation in custom CNN
I am an early career researcher in computational neuroscience, and I am currently trying to model a robust object recognition model.
My model takes a dataset (binary images; where each object is presented in the center of the image) as the input and convolves the data with 14 different kernel (so each object is being convolved with each kernel) and after that I apply a max pooling function on each feature map.
Now, I am trying to get a robust model, meaning I would like my model to still be able to classify the object, regardless of their position in the image.
After training my model and testing it on a manipulated dataset (i.e, objects are not in the center anymore, but in the upperleft corner of the image for example) the returned accuracies are pretty bad (0.05%). However, I unfortunately fail to understand this, because I always assumed that max pooling achieve positional invariance in the images?
Is anybody able to help me understand this and what possibly went wrong?
I must mention that I am not using a classical deep learning framework, rather I calculate the convolutional feature maps by using ndi.convolve(image,kernel) and after apply the maxpooling with skimages block_reduce (I tried torch.MaxPool2D() aswell though, but the returned features did not seem to differ much).
An example of the workflow would be this:
example_image = Dataset[0]
example_kernel = gabor_kernel(theta=0,frequency=0.3)
response = ndi.correlate(example_image ,example_kernel.real)
pool= measure.block_reduce(response,block_size(2,2),func=np.max)

I would appreciate any advice a lot. If anyone is wondering, I am not using the CNN functionality of a deep learning framework because a lot of features implemented in the model are based on theory, thats why the convolutional filters are not learnable but rather fixed in my model approach.
Anyhow, if you have any insight,or if I could provide more information on this matter, please let me know.
All the best
